# Django model form many to many field data how to insert?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

**Branch Model which to separate to data branch wise**

```
class Branch(models.Model): # Branch Master
    status_type = (
        ("a",'Active'),
        ("d",'Deactive'),
    )
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    suffix = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True)
    Remark = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices = status_type, default = 'a')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Vendor Model which is I am use to separate branch wise vendors**

```
class Vendor(models.Model):
    status_type = (
        ("a",'Active'),
        ("d",'Deactive'),
    )
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    branch = models.ManyToManyField(Branch)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique = True)
    email  =  models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique = True)
    gst = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique = True)
    pan_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique = True)
    add_1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank = True)
    add_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank = True)
    add_3 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank = True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    Remark = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices = status_type, default = 'a')
```

**this is forms.py file **

```
    class VendorForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model  = Vendor
            fields = '__all__'
            labels = {
                'add_1':'Address',
                'add_2':'Address',
                'add_3':'Address',
            }
            exclude = ['created_by']
            widgets = {
'branch':forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'',}),
                'company':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Company Name'}),
                'name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Name'}),
                'phone':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Phone'}),
                'email':forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Email'}),
                'gst':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'GST No.'}),
                'pan_no':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Pan No.'}),
                'add_1':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Address'}),
                'add_2':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Address'}),
                'add_3':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Address'}),
                'city':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'City'}),
                'state':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'State'}),
                'Remark':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control','rows':'2', 'placeholder':'Remark'}),
                'status':forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            }
```

**View.py Many to Many field is not insert i don't know what is problem vendor data is save but branch is field is not save  **

```
def Add_Vendor(request): # for vendor add
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            form = VendorForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid:
                forms = form.save(commit=False)
            forms.created_by = request.user
            forms.save()
                messages.success(request,'Vendor has been added.')
                return redirect('vendor_page')
        except:
            messages.error(request, str(form.errors))
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = VendorForm()
    context = {
        'form':form,
        'branch_data':request.session['branch_name'],
        'btn_type':'fa fa-regular fa-plus',
        'form_title':'Vendor Form',
        'tree_main_title':'Vendor',
        'v_url':'vendor_page',
        'tree_title':'Add Form',
    }
    return render(request, 'base/vendor_master/form_vendor.html', context)
```

**Vendor data save into data base but branch field is not insert into database **

Comment: Exactly *how* it is not saving, it does not save `Brach`, it simply links the vandor with the `Branch`...

Comment: Would `vendor_add.save_m2m()` after `vendor_add.save()` not be a good idea in this case @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike?

Comment: @raphael: well it is not very compatible with class-based views, often is forgotton, the `save_m2m` is not necessary here by the way, since it has both a `fields` and `exclude` which basically contradict each other.

Answer (score 1):

Just like the previous time, *don't* use `commit=False`: it prevents saving the many-to-many fields by default.

Your `if form.is_valid` will *always* succeed, since it is a method, and a method has truthiness `True`:

```
def Add_Vendor(request):  # for vendor add
    branch = get_object_or_404(Branch, pk=request.session['branch_id'])
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VendorForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.created_by = request.user
            vendor_add = form.save()
            vendor_add.branch.add(branch)
            messages.success(request, 'Vendor has been added.')
            return redirect('vendor_page')
        else:
            messages.error(request, str(form.errors))
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = VendorForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'branch_data': request.session['branch_name'],
        'btn_type': 'fa fa-regular fa-plus',
        'form_title': 'Vendor Form',
        'tree_main_title': 'Vendor',
        'v_url': 'vendor_page',
        'tree_title': 'Add Form',
    }
    return render(request, 'base/vendor_master/form_vendor.html', context)
```

That being said, session variables are often *not* a good idea. Indeed, it creates some sort of [*global state* antipattern [softwareengineering.se]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil), and it is not unthinkable that just before a person makes a request to the page, through some other page view, the session variables change/invalidate. Therefore giving the wrong impression that it will work with a different branch. Usually it is better to do things *explicitly* and thus add a parameter to the path that contains the primary key, or some other token of the branch to add.

The `Branch` model is however not suposed to update, it simply adds a link. That means that `myvendor.branch.all()` should now return that `Branch`, it thus links the two together, linking two items does not modify the (individual) items, hence the timestamp will *not* update.

---

> **Note**: Functions are normally written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, therefore it is
> advisable to rename your function to `add_vendor`, not <s>`Add_Vendor`</s>.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

---

> **Note**: While most forms do not process media files, it is probably better to pass [**`request.FILES`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) to the form anyway, such that if you later add an extra media field, all views that use the form will indeed handle the files properly.g

Comment: I have try but problem is same : b_id = request.session['branch_id']
    branch = get_object_or_404(Branch, id = b_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = VendorForm(request.POST)
        try:
            if form.is_valid:
                form.instance.created_by = request.user
                vendor_add = form.save()
                vendor_add.branch.add(branch)
                messages.success(request,'Vendor has been added.')
                return redirect('vendor_page')

Comment: @shyamrathod: don't use `if form.is_valid`... as said in the answer, it is `if form.is_valid()`...

Comment: Exactly how do you *inspect* the many-to-many relation?

Comment: I don't  know to inspect I have just save branch id which is I m passing on session

Comment: @shyamrathod: so how do you know it has (not) been saved/added?

Comment: session branch id I have check  using print

Comment: @shyamrathod: I mean how do you know it was *not* added to the created `Vendor`?

Comment: it show on django admin panel

Comment: @shyamrathod: how?

Comment: when I have to submit the vendor form all details is save on database but only branch field is not save

Comment: @shyamrathod: but branch is *not* a field, `branch` is not stored as column in the database (you can look at this), it works as a junction table.  You can not just add `branch` in the `list_display`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254639/discussion-between-shyam-rathod-and-willem-vo-supports-mod-strike).

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem with form validation in your views.py
you should use:

```
if form.is_valid():
```

and you should make sure that the "branch_id" exists

to add branch to vendor, you should first save the vendor object without committing to database then add the branch to vendor and then save the vendor object again so the "Add_Vendor" function should be like this:

```
def Add_Vendor(request): # for vendor add
    b_id = request.session['branch_id']
    # check if b_id exists
    if b_id is None:
        messages.error(request, 'Branch not selected. Please select a branch first.')
        return redirect('select_branch_page') # redirect to the branch selecting page

    branch_id = Branch.objects.get(id = b_id)
    print(branch_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = VendorForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            vendor_add = form.save(commit=False)
            vendor_add.created_by = request.user
            vendor_add.save()
            vendor_add.branch.add(branch_id)
            vendor_add.save() # Save the vendor again to persist the changes with the branch.
            messages.success(request, 'Vendor has been added.')
            return redirect('vendor_page')
        else:
            messages.error(request, str(form.errors))
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = VendorForm()
    context = {
        'form':form,
        'branch_data':request.session['branch_name'],
        'btn_type':'fa fa-regular fa-plus',
        'form_title':'Vendor Form',
        'tree_main_title':'Vendor',
        'v_url':'vendor_page',
        'tree_title':'Add Form',
    }
    return render(request, 'base/vendor_master/form_vendor.html', context)
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: facing same problem